# Final Grade Section not working on a letter, word, sentence count program

Tags: c, formula, cs50, calculation

Why does the final section, Grade, not calculate? 
I mean, why is it not carrying through to the final section of the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    char text[1000];
    int number = 0;
    int words = 0, i;
    int sentences = 0, j;
    float l = ((number +1) / (words +1)) * 100;
    float s = ((sentences+1) / (words+1)) * 100;
    float index = (0.0588 * l) - 0.296 * s - 15.8;

    // Text Input = Text //

    printf("Text: ");
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
    printf("%s", text);

    // Letters = number //

    number = strlen(text);
    printf("%d letters\n", number);

    // Words = words //

    for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ' && text[i+1] != ' ')
        words++;
    }
    printf("%d words\n", words);

    // Sentences = sentences

    for (j = 0; j < strlen(text); j++)
        {if (text[j] == '.' || text[j] == '!' || text[j] == '?')
            sentences++;
        }

        printf("%d sentences\n", sentences);

    // grade level based on formula //

    if (index >= 1 && index <= 16)
        {
            printf("Grade %f\n", index);
        }
             else
                {
                  if (index < 1)
                    {
                printf("Before Grade 1\n");
                    }

                if (index > 16)
                    {
                printf("Grade 16+\n");
                    }
                }
        }
```

Any feedback would be of significance.

I suspect it's due to the integer identities assigned to the initial variables of number, words, and sentences, yet I do not have a clue how to improve upon this. It's just the final grade portion that is impeding my progress and understanding.

Comment: `((number + 1) / (words + 1)) ` is integer division. i.e. truncated. Make either the numerator or denominator floating point (change the 1 to 1.0 or some such) and see the difference. The same problem happens with `((sentences+1) / (words+1))`. And fyi, your compiler should warn you about conversion from into to float losing precision and possible data loss on both of those; if it didn't you need to crank up your warning levels. Of course, since neither `number` nor `words` is meaningful, those values are pointless. You should compute `l` and `s` *after* your text processing sets `words` etc.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  Please do not use tabs for indenting